# Exit time of Brownian motion with random variables.

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ $B$ a Brownian motion, $U$ a non-negative random variable and $V$ a random variable, which $V\overset{d}{=}-U$. I am trying to understand why the next random variable is a stopping time
\begin{equation}
\tau=\inf\{t\geq0|B_t\notin(V,U)\}
\end{equation}
for some filtration $\mathbb{F}=\{\mathcal{F}_t|t\geq0\}$. My guess is
\begin{equation}
[\tau\leq t]=[B_t\leq V]\cup[B_t\geq U]
\end{equation}
then if $\mathbb{F}$ is a filtration for which $B$ is Brownian motion and $U$ is $\mathcal{F}_0$ measurable, then $\tau$ is a stopping time. But I am not very sure if I am right, any help or advice is welcome. Thanks!.

Comment: The event $\{\tau\leq t\}$ can be stated in words as "there exists $s\in[0,t]$ such that $B_s \notin (V,U)$". In particular, it is **not** equal to $\{B_t\leq V\}\cup\{B_t\geq U\}$. Do you know how to prove the statement when $U$ and $V$ are not random ?

Comment: I found the proof when $U,V$ are not random on https://planetmath.org/hittingtimesarestoppingtimes because the Brownian motion has continuous paths and $(U,V)^C$ is a closed set. Another way is using the fact that  $\tau_a=\inf\{t\geq0|B_t=a\}$ is a stopping time, so $\tau=\tau_U\wedge\tau_V$ is a stopping time. Both in both ways I don't understand how to do it in this case.

Comment: I was thinking if I define the processes $BU_t=B_t-U$ and $BV_t=B_t-V$ then both has continuous paths, and the first passage times when they hit $0$ ($\tau_{BU}=\inf\{t\geq0|BU_t=0\}$ and $\tau_{BV}=\inf\{t\geq0|BV_t=0\}$) are a stopping time, so minimum of them is also a stopping time $(\tau=\tau_{BU}\wedge\tau_{BV}\}$. Is that right?

Comment: yup, that is right :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! <3